# MSSQL Replication: If Publisher/Distributor server goes down

Tags: sql-server, replication, load-balancing

**Background**

To make the story short, our company is facing the task of making our application redudant and more resilent to heavy loads by load-balancing. The task is on my desk and I've been doing some research as I've never done it before.

**Fact**

Today we host our application on 1 server and the goal is to have another one to even out serverload with load-balacing.

**Issue**

I've been doing some research and got stuck on how to setup the MSSQL Replication. If one server goes down the other one must be in sync as the users will be redirected there insted by the load-balancer

The tenthousand view to the solution goes something like: Have a Publisher/Distributor on same server and then add subscriber databases and they will sync between eachother.

**Question**

What happens if the Publisher/Distrubtor server goes down? Suddenly the system isn't redudant at all. Do we have to setup a Publisher/Distrubtor on each subscriber server to take over the role? I've been search around and haven't found a good answer.

Just hint if the explanation is confusing and I'll fill in the blanks..

Thanks in advance!